# Creating N threads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I trying to create N threads in the following manner:
The main thread creates a thread, which in turn creates another, and so forth N times. That is the child of the main thread creates a thread, and the child of that child creates a thread and so forth. I understand how to do it fork

```
     int p;
     int i=1; int N = 10;
     do {
         p = fork() ;
     } while ((p ==0) && (++i<=N));
```

Is there a way of doing it with threads?

Comment: Well, yes.  Have you read any of the pthreads documentation/examples?  Why do you need a hierarchy of threads instead of all created from the main thread?

Comment: @OldProgrammer: an assignment from school that's why.

Comment: What exactly would this do regarding threads? Seems dangerous to copy the same stackframe within one process. Imagine `void * mem= malloc(50); do {thread_fork();/*does not exist for a reason*/}while ((p ==0) && (++i<=N)); free(mem);`. Just create them all from one thread and define an entry point instead of just doing the "start from the same instruction" think that fork does.

Comment: @PeterT: the code has nothing to do with threads. I just wanted to know if there was a way to create a hierarchy of thread as the code does with `fork()`. Perhaps I shouldn’t have posted the code so as not to create confusion.

Comment: the code has the fork() in a loop, so the parent will generate n child processes.  process 1 (a child of main process) will generate n-1 processes, etc.  the best approach is to remove the loop, so each process only generates one thread, with a counter, init to 0, incremented and passed to the next child process, along with 'n'.  the process generation to stop when the passed counter reachs the 'n' limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read some [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) & [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html).

You create a thread with [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) (and it can fail). You give a routine and an argument (usually heap allocated). Some analogy with `fork`.

A thread routine can itself call `pthread_create`.

Later, you'll better call [pthread_join(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) somewhere (some analogy with `waitpid`), or else use [pthread_detach(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html)

Remember that by definition all [threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) of the same [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) share a *common* [address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) (and other things like current directory, opened file descriptors table, etc...)

BTW, what you want to do is usually uncommon and error-prone. Threads are expensive resources! In practice, you should have a few dozen threads at most (make the maximum configurable, and default it to the numbers of cores on your processor), and you should care about synchronization (using mutexes and condition variables, etc...). You might want to have your [thread pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern). Read also about [producer-consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).

Comment: Yes, I understand the consequence of what I'm trying to do and it's not  a common practice, but it's a school assignment. 
By routine you mean a function that I'll pass as an argument when creating the thread?

Comment: So if I understand well,  in this routine I call `pthread_create()` without forgetting to join. The thread created then calls this same routine and so on?

Comment: Yes; but the starting argument should usually be heap allocated.